# Pasar el "Login" en java y base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, login

estoy tratando de hacer un login en java y mysql pero a la hora de intentar pasar el login me falla y no se el por que... me tira el mensaje de"Errrror".
tengo un JFrame con el boton de login que seria este:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //validar
    Usuario usu1=new Usuario(TxtUsuario.getText(),txtPassword.getText());
    try
    {
        Usuarios usuarios=new Usuarios();
        int res=-1;
        res=usuarios.BuscarPorNombre(usu1);

        if(res>=0)
        {
            frmPrincipal principal=new frmPrincipal();

            principal.setVisible(true);

            this.dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Errrror");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

}

y esta clase de usuarios con este metodo:

```
public int BuscarPorNombre(Usuario nuevo)
{
    String sql="select NombreUsuario,PassUsuario from usuario where NombreUsuario=?";
    int res=-1;
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement st=cnn.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, nuevo.NombreUsuario);
        res=st.executeUpdate();


    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        //procesar
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Porque usas PreparedStatement si no estás insertando o actualizando datos, solo estás haciendo consultas

Comment: estas usando el metodo equivocado. No se usa executeUpdate() para un select, deberias usar un **executeQuery();**

Comment: Y como quedaría? que al cambiarlo me tira una serie de errores :/

Comment: Te recomiendo mostrar el mensaje de error completo ya que nos pueden indicar la fuente exacta del error, y no parafrasear el mensaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para leer una consulta de bd necesitas un ResultSet:

```
    java.sql.Resultset rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

y para ver si encontró algo:

```
    boolean encontróUsuario = rs.next();
```

Si quieres ver la contraseña del usuario, entonces después del rs.next() agregas:

```
    if (encontróUsuario) {
        String contraseña = rs.getString(2); //<<ya que es la segunda columna en tu consulta sql.
    }
```

Por otro lado yo no cacharía la sqlException en el método para buscar, porque así vas a confundir un "cliente no encontrado, o contraseña incorrecta" con un error de sql.

Además, estás creando un PerparedStatement en cada búsqueda, y pierdes el propósito del mismo, que es tenerlo ya preparado. Yo lo tendría ya creado y lo referenciaría en cada búsqueda. Algo tipo:

```
    public java.sql.PreparedStatement dameStatementDeBusqueda() {
        if (statement == null) {
           ///aquí creo el pstatment, pero solo una vez.
        }
        return statement;
   }
```

Comment: Ok muchas gracias lo probare

Comment: Sigue tirando el error :/

Comment: podras copiar la excepción o error que te genera? el error es en la compilación o en la ejecución?